# Weighted graph and pathfinding implementation in C#

Tags: c#, graph, pathfinding

I am implementing fundamental data structures in C#. I have written a weighted graph in Java so my main motivation here is to sharpen my skills in C#. I have tested with various cases and there seems to be no logical issues, but I know the language could be better utilized.

The `Pathfinder` method is not absolutely necessary, because the only difference with A* and Dijkstra is the Heuristic.  The reason I have it is two-fold. There are various optimizations of A* that I would like to implement in the future. Thus I want it to be isolated. I also want to master delegates, hence the use of Func.

As always, I am open to any general or specific advice.

**`WeightedGraph`**

```
class WeightedGraph<T>
{
    List<WeightedEdge<T>> edges;
    List<Vertex<T>> vertices;
    public List<WeightedEdge<T>> Edges { get { return edges; } }

    public WeightedGraph(List<Vertex<T>> vertices, List<WeightedEdge<T>> edges)
    {
        this.vertices = vertices;
        this.edges = edges;
    }
    public void AddEdge(WeightedEdge<T> newEdge)
    {
        edges.Add(newEdge);
    }
    public void RemoveEdge(WeightedEdge<T> edge)
    {
        edges.Remove(edge);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Pathfinding algorithms available: Dijkstra and AStar
    /// </summary>
    public List<Vertex<T>> Pathfinder(Vertex<T> start, Vertex<T> end, string algorithm)
    {
        Func<Vertex<T>, Vertex<T>, List<Vertex<T>>> pathfinder;

        if (algorithm == "Dijkstra")
        {
            pathfinder = DijkstraSearch;
        }
        else if (algorithm == "AStar")
        {
            pathfinder = AStarSearch;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Pathfinding algorithm not available.");
        }
        return pathfinder(start, end);
    }


    public List<Vertex<T>> DijkstraSearch(Vertex<T> start, Vertex<T> end)
    {
        Dictionary<Vertex<T>, Vertex<T>> parentMap = new Dictionary<Vertex<T>, Vertex<T>>();
        PriorityQueue<Vertex<T>> priorityQueue = new PriorityQueue<Vertex<T>>();

        InitializeCosts(start);
        priorityQueue.Enqueue(start, start.Cost);

        Vertex<T> current;

        while (priorityQueue.Count > 0)
        {
            current = priorityQueue.Dequeue();

            if (!current.IsVisited)
            {
                current.IsVisited = true;

                if (current.Equals(end))
                {
                    break;
                }

                foreach (WeightedEdge<T> edge in current.Edges)
                {
                    Vertex<T> neighbor = edge.End;

                    double newCost = current.Cost + edge.Weight;
                    double neighborCost = neighbor.Cost;

                    if (newCost < neighborCost)
                    {
                        neighbor.Cost = newCost;
                        parentMap.Add(neighbor, current);
                        double priority = newCost;
                        priorityQueue.Enqueue(neighbor, priority);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        List<Vertex<T>> path = ReconstructPath(parentMap, start, end);
        return path;
    }

    public List<Vertex<T>> AStarSearch(Vertex<T> start, Vertex<T> end)
    {
        Dictionary<Vertex<T>, Vertex<T>> parentMap = new Dictionary<Vertex<T>, Vertex<T>>();
        PriorityQueue<Vertex<T>> priorityQueue = new PriorityQueue<Vertex<T>>();

        InitializeCosts(start);
        priorityQueue.Enqueue(start, start.Cost);

        Vertex<T> current;

        while (priorityQueue.Count > 0)
        {
            current = priorityQueue.Dequeue();

            if (!current.IsVisited)
            {
                current.IsVisited = true;

                if (current.Equals(end))
                {
                    break;
                }

                foreach (WeightedEdge<T> edge in current.Edges)
                {
                    Vertex<T> neighbor = edge.End;

                    double newCost = current.Cost + edge.Weight;
                    double neighborCost = neighbor.Cost;

                    if (newCost < neighborCost)
                    {
                        neighbor.Cost = newCost;
                        parentMap.Add(neighbor, current);
                        double priority = newCost + Heuristic(neighbor, end);
                        priorityQueue.Enqueue(neighbor, priority);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        List<Vertex<T>> path = ReconstructPath(parentMap, start, end);
        return path;
    }

    public double Heuristic(Vertex<T> vertexA, Vertex<T> vertexB)
    {
        return vertexA.Location.DistanceTo(vertexB.Location);
    }

    public void InitializeCosts(Vertex<T> start)
    {
        foreach (Vertex<T> vertex in vertices)
        {
            vertex.Cost = int.MaxValue;
        }

        start.Cost = 0;
    }

    public List<Vertex<T>> ReconstructPath(Dictionary<Vertex<T>, Vertex<T>> parentMap, Vertex<T> start, Vertex<T> end)
    {
        List<Vertex<T>> path = new List<Vertex<T>>();
        Vertex<T> current = end;

        while (current != start)
        {
            path.Add(current);
            current = parentMap[current];
        }

        path.Add(start);

        path.Reverse();
        return path;
    }

}
```

**`Vertex`**

```
class Vertex<T>
{
    List<Vertex<T>> neighbors;
    List<WeightedEdge<T>> edges;
    T value;

    public List<Vertex<T>> Neighbors { get { return neighbors; } }
    public List<WeightedEdge<T>> Edges { get { return edges; } }
    public Location Location { get; set; }
    public T Value { get { return value; } set { this.value = value; } }
    public bool IsVisited { get; set; }
    public int NeighborsCount { get { return neighbors.Count; } }
    public double Cost { get; set; }

    public Vertex(T value)
    {
        this.value = value;
        IsVisited = false;
        neighbors = new List<Vertex<T>>();
        edges = new List<WeightedEdge<T>>();
    }

    public Vertex(T value, List<Vertex<T>> neighbors)
    {
        this.value = value;
        IsVisited = false;
        this.neighbors = neighbors;
    }

    public void AddNeighbor(Vertex<T> vertex)
    {
        neighbors.Add(vertex);
    }
    public void AddEdge(WeightedEdge<T> edge)
    {
        edges.Add(edge);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        StringBuilder allNeighbors = new StringBuilder("");
        allNeighbors.Append(value + ": ");

        foreach (Vertex<T> neighbor in neighbors)
        {
            allNeighbors.Append(neighbor.value + "  ");
        }

        return allNeighbors.ToString();
    }

}
```

**`WeightedEdge`**

```
class WeightedEdge<T>
{
    int weight;

    Vertex<T> start;
    Vertex<T> end;

    public int Weight { get { return weight; } }

    public Vertex<T> Start { get { return start; } }
    public Vertex<T> End { get { return end; } }

    public WeightedEdge(Vertex<T> start, Vertex<T> end, int weight)
    {
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
        this.weight = weight;
        start.AddNeighbor(end);
        start.AddEdge(this);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}--{1}-->{2}", start.Value, weight, end.Value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**WeightedGraph**

This class shoudln't implement any search algorithms. They need to be injected. Let's do this...

First you change the signature of the `Pathfinder` method to accept an interface instead of a *magic string*:

```
public List<Vertex<T>> Pathfinder<TSearchAlgorithm>(Vertex<T> start, Vertex<T> end) 
    where TSearchAlgorithm : ISearchAlgorithm, new()
{
    var searchAlgorithm = new TSearchAlgorithm();
    return searchAlgorithm.Search(start, end);      
}
```

you use the `new()` constraint to be able to create an instance of the generic argument that at the same time must implement the interface below that requires one method for searching:

```
interface ISearchAlgorithm
{ 
    List<Vertex<T>> Search<T>(Vertex<T> start, Vertex<T> end);
}
```

you implement this interface in two classes, one for each search algorithm *(here only one)*:

```
class DijkstraSearchAlgorithm : ISearchAlgorithm
{
    public List<Vertex<T>> Search<T>(Vertex<T> start, Vertex<T> end)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

now if you call it like this:

```
weightedGraph.Pathfinder<DijkstraSearchAlgorithm>(..., ...);
```

instead of *magic strings* real magic happens ;-)

---

**Access modifiers**

Although not requried for private fields, it's a good habit to use them anyway to avoid any confusion.

**Edges property**

> ```
> List<WeightedEdge<T>> edges;
> public List<WeightedEdge<T>> Edges { get { return edges; } }
> ```

You provide additional methods for adding and removing edges... but currently the user is free to modify the list anyway becasue you expose it to him. Either remove the add/remove-edge methods or make the property `IReadOnlyCollection<WeightedEdge<T>>` so that he cannot change it.

---

**Search algorithms**

I see that your search algorithms share one method: `ReconstructPath`.

If you don't want to repeat it in each algorithm you can as well create an abstract class that already implements it and derive the search algorithms from it:

```
interface ISearchAlgorithm
{ 
    List<Vertex<T>> Search<T>(Vertex<T> start, Vertex<T> end);
}

abstract class SearchAlgorithm : ISearchAlgorithm
{
    public abstract List<Vertex<T>> Search<T>(Vertex<T> start, Vertex<T> end);

    protected List<Vertex<T>> ReconstructPath<T>(Dictionary<Vertex<T>, Vertex<T>> parentMap, Vertex<T> start, Vertex<T> end)
    {
        ...
    }
}

class DijkstraSearchAlgorithm : SearchAlgorithm
{
    public override List<Vertex<T>> Search<T>(Vertex<T> start, Vertex<T> end)
    {
        ...
    }       
}
```

Comment: Wow the interface is a fantastic idea. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Vardominator I've added one more edit about the `ReconstructPath` method ;-)

Comment: These are some great things things to consider. Off to editing. Thanks!

Comment: Actually this does not work because the SearchAlgorithm class does not know what 'T' is.

Comment: @Vardominator do you think that or did you try it out because before I posted the code I've tested it in LINQPad and everything was fine so I'm pretty sure it's correct... could you post your code as an answer to this question?

Comment: @Vardominator or to pastebin or something like that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43852/discussion-between-vardominator-and-t3chb0t).